# Wordpress display specific sub category of a parent category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So here's the scenario, I'm building a theme that would display sub category of a parent post

for Food:
[Food]
->Hotdog
->Eggs
->Fries

for Toys:
[Toys]
->Doll
->Car
->Drums

for People:
[People]
->Mom
->Dad
->Uncle

now I don't want to display their parent category, just their subcategory (eg Doll, Car, Drums). I've looked list_cats() and wp_list_categories() but I can't figure out how to display it right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `get_categories` for that.

```
<?php
$subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=4');
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
  // var_dump($subcategory);
}
?>
```

**Update**: A more complete example:

```
<?php
$subcategories = get_categories('&child_of=4&hide_empty'); // List subcategories of category '4' (even the ones with no posts in them)
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
  echo sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_category_link($subcategory->term_id), apply_filters('get_term', $subcategory->name));
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: can you give me an idea how to apply this? I tried putting it on my theme but nothing happens, I also tried changing the value for my parent category, same nothing happens...  thanks!